# Groovy: Timeout due to proxy not being set (java.net.ConnectException) HTTPS

Tags: groovy, https, proxy

I want to use a Groovy script to access a webpage using HTTPS URL. This questions is discussed earler with HTTP example, but there no solution for HTTPS URLS

Here's a test script that fails...

```
System.properties << [ 'http.proxyHost':'proxy', 'http.proxyPort':'9999', 'http.proxyUserName':'user', 'http.proxyPassword':'pass' ]
println 'https://www.google.com'.toURL().text
```

Here's the output...

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

    at rest_client.run(rest_client.groovy:13)
```

With HTTP URL script is working.

What I must do for HTTPS connecting?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html :

> ### HTTPS
>
> The https (http over SSL) protocol handler has its own set of properties:
>
> ```
> htttps.proxyHost
> https.proxyPort
> ```
>
> As you probably guessed these work in the exact same manner as their http counterparts, so we won't go into much detail except to mention that the default port number, this time, is 443 and that for the "non proxy hosts" list, the HTTPS protocol handler will use the same as the http handler (i.e. http.nonProxyHosts).

Comment: I did changes in my proxy settings, but now I have an error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target